# How to web scrape an ASPX page that requires authentication

Tags: python, asp.net, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

Using the python's library 'Requests', I'm trying to web scrape an ASPX site (https://cei.bmfbovespa.com.br/CEI_Responsivo/home.aspx) that requires a login first (https://cei.bmfbovespa.com.br/CEI_Responsivo/login.aspx).

Here are the steps that I'm trying to do:

1. Create a Session with 'Requests' to handle the cookies (it does right?)
2. Update the header with all the information that I got from "Request Header" with Chrome Developing Tool (except the cookie's information because of the Session)
3. Do a GET in the login page to have the input values for the POST
4. POST

When I manually do this with chrome, after a succeded login, I got a '302 response' and I'm redirected to the homepage. But with python, after the POST, I got a '200 response' and I'm still in the login page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.packages.urllib3 import add_stderr_logger

add_stderr_logger()

s = requests.Session()

url_login = 'https://cei.bmfbovespa.com.br/CEI_Responsivo/login.aspx'

headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'Host':'cei.bmfbovespa.com.br',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Accept-Language':'pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
}
s.headers.update(headers)

r = s.get(url_login, verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

viewstate = soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")['value']
viewgen = soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']
eventvalid = soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']

login_data = {          
        '__VIEWSTATE' : viewstate,
        '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' : viewgen,
        '__EVENTVALIDATION' : eventvalid,
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtLogin' : '*',
        'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSenha' : '*',
        'tl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLogar': 'Entrar'
}

resp = s.post(url_login, data=login_data, verify=False)
```

If I still try to do a GET with the Session, I'm redirected to the login page:

```
url_carteira = 'https://cei.bmfbovespa.com.br/CEI_Responsivo/home.aspx'
response = s.get(url_carteira, verify=False)
```

And that's the output that I receive:

```
2016-02-11 22:07:07,476 INFO Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cei.bmfbovespa.com.br
2016-02-11 22:07:07,823 DEBUG "GET /CEI_Responsivo/login.aspx HTTP/1.1" 200 4522
2016-02-11 22:07:07,898 DEBUG "POST /CEI_Responsivo/login.aspx HTTP/1.1" 200 4534
C:\Users\luciano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:791: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html
  InsecureRequestWarning)
2016-02-11 22:07:10,470 DEBUG "GET /CEI_Responsivo/home.aspx HTTP/1.1" 302 147
2016-02-11 22:07:10,510 DEBUG "GET /CEI_Responsivo/login.aspx HTTP/1.1" 200 4522
```

I'm using python 3.5.1

Any idea of why I can't successfully login and acess the homepage?