# Scraping an ASPX page with authentication. Using Python 3

Tags: asp.net, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to use python`s requests library to scrape an ASPX site and get information from a Table inside.

The problem I am experiencing has also been well described in [How to web scrape an ASPX page that requires authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352682/how-to-web-scrape-an-aspx-page-that-requires-authentication#new-answer) with no replies at the time of writing.

The way I am currently going about it is by:

- creating a requests session,
- fetching a request header.
- The information received from the get request is parsed using BeautifulSoup.
- Setting all of the parameters to a login_data dictionary.

  ```
   import urllib.parse
   import requests
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


   headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36"}

   with requests.session() as session:
       session.headers.update(headers)
       response=session.get(login_url)
       soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content)

       VIEWSTATE = soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")['value']
       VIEWSTATEGENERATOR = soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']
       EVENTVALIDATION = soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']
       EVENTTARGET = soup.find(id="__EVENTTARGET")['value']
       EVENTARGUEMENT = soup.find(id="__EVENTARGUMENT")['value']
       PREVIOUSPAGE = soup.find(id="__PREVIOUSPAGE")['value']
       CMSESSIONID = soup.find(id="CMSessionId")['value']

       soup.find(id="MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_userNameTextbox")['value']

       login_data= {
           "__VIEWSTATE" : VIEWSTATE,
           "txtUserName" : account_name,
           "txtPassword" : account_pass,
           "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" : VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,
           "__EVENTVALIDATION": EVENTVALIDATION,
           "__EVENTTARGET" : EVENTTARGET,
           "__EVENTARGUEMENT" : EVENTARGUEMENT,
           "__PREVIOUSPAGE" : PREVIOUSPAGE,
           "CMSessionId" : CMSESSIONID,
           "MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_userNameTextbox" : account_name,
           "MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_passwordTextbox" : account_pass,
           "MasterHeaderPlaceHolder_ctl00_tempPasswordTextbox" : account_pass
            }

       login_data_encoded = urllib.parse.urlencode(login_data) #*
  ```

Further to this, the login_data dictionary is being passed to a post request to the login_url as the data.

The same session is then used to try and get the request from the report_url.

```
response_1 = session.post(login_url, data=login_data)
response_2 = session.get(report_url)
```

The problem seems to be that the login is not being effected. as the get request is being re-routed to a login page.

Can anyone kindly shed some light on why this is the case? I am guessing that this is the correct flow, however please let me know if there is anything I am doing wrong or that can be improved.

I am unfortunately currently limited to using only requests or other popular python 3 libraries as it is a requirement (using references to "browser".exe files, as suggested in some replies on the subject, is not an option.)